# Trying to find RV's $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ satisfying $\mathbf{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbf{P}(N=0)+\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf{P}(C_j\leq y)\mathbf{P}(N=j).$

Tags: probability

This is an assignment question that I just can't puzzle out; some hints or direction would be appreciated. We're given fixed parameters $p \in [0,1]$ and $m,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. We also given a natural number $n$, together with a couple of $n$-long sequences of iid random variables, distributed like so: $$A_j \sim \mathrm{Binom}(1,p) \quad B_j \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(m,\lambda).$$

A couple of comments:

- The notation $\mathrm{Gamma}(m,\lambda)$ means the gamma distribution with shape parameter $m$ and **rate** parameter $\lambda$.
- We assume that $A_j$ is independent of $B_{k}$ for all relevant $j,k.$

Now let $Y$ denote the sum $$Y = \sum_{j=1}^n A_j B_j$$

and $A$ denote the sum $$N = \sum_{j=1}^n A_j.$$

By independence of the $A_j$'s, it follows that $$N \sim \mathrm{Binom}(n,p).$$

All well and good, but here's where I get stuck. It says:

> Using the Law of Total Probability, find RV's $C_j \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(jm,\lambda)$ satisfying $$\mathbf{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbf{P}(N=0)+\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf{P}(C_j\leq y)\mathbf{P}(N=j).$$

There's no stipulation that the $C_j$'s have to be iid.

Idea anyone? Some hints or direction would be nice.

Comment: The choice $C_j=B_1+\cdots+B_j$ works.

Comment: @Did, thanks. Let me try proving that.